# Handling retries and throttling in microsoft graph API SDK

Tags: go, microsoft-graph-sdks

The current microsoft graph SDK for Go doesn't specify any parameters for the graph client to leverage throttling or retries, or anything to determine the default behaviour.

It can be done based on response codes if you use a custom REST client by looking at the error code 429 and backoff time from the response headers but not from using the sdk.

Looking for a solution so that the graph sdk internally retries within the `Retry-After` header

The doc also doesn't mention any custom adapters for a throttling handle
https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-go-core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i was able to figure out how to add a retry handler as a middleware to the graph client in Go. here is the piece of code:

```
// Generate credentials
cred, err := azidentity.NewClientSecretCredential(sharepointTenantId, clientId, clientSecret, nil)

if err != nil {
    return err
}

defaultClientOptions := msgraphsdk.GetDefaultClientOptions()
defaultMiddleWare := msgraphgocore.GetDefaultMiddlewaresWithOptions(&defaultClientOptions)


// Custom middleware function to retry only on ratelimit error (Code: 429) can be customized to retry on more error codes)

graphRetryOptions := nethttplibrary.RetryHandlerOptions{MaxRetries: 5, ShouldRetry: func(delay time.Duration, executionCount int, request *http.Request, response *http.Response) bool {
    if response.StatusCode == 429 {
        if v := response.Header["Retry-After"]; len(v) > 0 {
            // Logic to add sleep based on retry after recommended time
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}}

retryMiddleware := nethttplibrary.NewRetryHandlerWithOptions(graphRetryOptions)
defaultMiddleWare = append(defaultMiddleWare, retryMiddleware)

graphOpts := &msgraphgocore.GraphClientOptions{GraphServiceVersion: DefaultGraphScope, GraphServiceLibraryVersion: "1.0.0"}

graphHttpClient := msgraphgocore.GetDefaultClient(graphOpts, defaultMiddleWare...)

authProvider, _ := authentication.NewAzureIdentityAuthenticationProviderWithScopes(cred, []string{".default"})

adapter, err := msgraphsdk.NewGraphRequestAdapterWithParseNodeFactoryAndSerializationWriterFactoryAndHttpClient(authProvider, nil, serialization.DefaultSerializationWriterFactoryInstance, graphHttpClient)


if err != nil {
    return err
}

// your graph client
client := msgraphsdk.NewGraphServiceClient(adapter)
```

Answer (score 0):

The SDK has retry handling baked in, so there's no need to reimplement it. The default middleware is defined in [kiota-http-go](https://github.com/microsoft/kiota-http-go/blob/36a913bf03c3d71136195d451498aefb7981f221/kiota_client_factory.go#L78)

The [retry logic](https://github.com/microsoft/kiota-http-go/blob/36a913bf03c3d71136195d451498aefb7981f221/retry_handler.go#L127) is also there. It handles 429, 503, and 504.